# Postive definiteness of block matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

I'm going to write a lower-size version of my question. **The Solution or hint for this one might be sufficient as well.**

> Let
> $G=\begin{bmatrix} A & B\\
> C&D
> \end{bmatrix}
> $
> where
> $$A_{11}=2C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_1\rangle)=2$$
> $$A_{12}=2C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle) +i(\eta_{11}\eta_{22}-\eta_{12}\eta_{21})C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle)$$
> $$A_{21}=\overline{A_{12}}$$
> $$A_{22}=2C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle\eta_2,\eta_2\rangle)=2$$
>
> So $A$ is a hermitian matrix.
>
> $$B_{11}=0$$
> $$B_{12}=(\eta_{11}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{21})C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle) +i(\eta_{12}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{22})C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle)$$
>
> $$B_{21}=-B_{12}$$
> $$B_{22}=0$$
>
> $$C=-\overline{B}$$ i.e., $C_{11}=C_{22}=0, $ $C_{12}=-\overline{B_{12}}, $ and $C_{21}=\overline{B_{12}}$,
> and
> $$D=\overline{A}$$ i.e., $D_{11}=D_{22}=2, $ $D_{12}=\overline{A_{12}}, $ and $D_{21}=A_{12}$.
>
> where $\eta_{i}=(\eta_{i1},\eta_{i2},\eta_{i3})$ (we have only two points) are the points on the unit sphere. And $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product.
>
> **Prove that $G$ is positive definite for almost every random choice of points.**

> **Edit after a comment**

\begin{align*}
 \det(G)&=16+\vert A_{12}\vert^{4}-\vert B_{12}\vert^{4}-8(\vert A_{12}\vert^{2}+\vert B_{12}\vert^{2})\\
           &\;\;\; +2\vert A_{12}\vert^{2}\vert B_{12}\vert^{2}+(\vert A_{12}\vert^{2}S+\vert B_{12}\vert^{2}T)i-TS
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 \vert A_{12}\vert^{2}&=4 \big(C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)\big)^{2}+(\eta_{11}\eta_{22}-\eta_{12}\eta_{21})^{2} \big( C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)\big)^{2}\\
 \vert B_{12}\vert^{2}&=(\eta_{11}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{21})^{2} \big( C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle)\big)^{2} +(\eta_{12}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{22})^{2} \big( C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle\eta_1,\eta_2\rangle)\big)^{2}\\
 T&=4\, C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)\, C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)\, (\eta_{11}\eta_{22}-\eta_{12}\eta_{21})\\
 S&=2\,\big(C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)\big)^{2}\, (\eta_{11}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{21})\, (\eta_{12}\eta_{23}-\eta_{13}\eta_{22})\\
\end{align*}

I understand that $C_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)=\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle=\cos(\theta)$ and $C_{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\langle \eta_{1},\eta_{2} \rangle)=1$. But even after this it's not obvious that the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Several questions: 1. does your $A_{13}$ have a typo? Others are $C_2^{1/2}$, this one is $C_3^{1/2}$. 2. It seems that we have concrete formulas for these two polynomials $C_2^{1/2}$ and $C_1^{1/2}$, and they are very easy. Is that right? 3. Can you provide some background where this question comes from? Are you sure of your guess that the matrix is positive definite?

Comment: @Threeaggies It's positive semidefinite and numerical calculation shows that it's positive definite. Also, I edited a lot.

Comment: @Hamit your question is still not clear. The lower dimension case, the vector $\eta$ are 3 dimensional or 2 dimensional?

Comment: @Kroki edited accordingly

Comment: I think the first step is to get rid of the $C^a_i(x)$ notation. You're only using i=0,1,2. there are explicity formulas for these cases. The second thing might be the observation that the remaining terms are the coordinates of the cross-product $\eta_1\times\eta_2$. With these things in mind, the result start to sound pretty reasonable.

Comment: @HudsonLima I edited.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, I think the answer is not very hard.

First, your Gegenbauer polynomials are very simple
$$
C_1^{\frac{1}{2}}(x)=x,\quad C_0^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)=1.
$$

Second, without loss of generality, you can always make one point $\eta_1$ on $S^2$ to be the north pole, and write the other one in spherical coordinates. Let me use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the usual $\phi$ and $\theta$ angles. **(See the end for a further simplification.)** Then clearly
$$
\langle \eta_1, \eta_2\rangle =\cos\alpha.
$$
Putting them together as rows, we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
\sin\alpha\cos\beta & \sin\alpha\sin\beta & \cos\alpha
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then the entries in your matrix are nothing but certain $2\times 2$ minors (they are also coordinates of the cross product $\eta_1\times\eta_2$).

Then you can work out your matrix $A$ and $B$ concretely.
\begin{gather}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\cos\alpha\\
2\cos\alpha & 2
\end{pmatrix},\\
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(\sin\alpha) (\cos\beta + i\sin\beta)\\
(\sin\alpha) (\cos\beta + i\sin\beta) & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(\sin\alpha) e^{i\beta}\\
(\sin\alpha) e^{i\beta} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{gather}

Here $A=\bar A^T$ is Hermitian, and $B=-B^T$ is skew-symmetric.

Your total matrix
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
-\bar B & \bar A
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
\bar B^T & \bar A
\end{pmatrix}
 $$
is a Hermitian matrix. To check whether it is positive-definite, we only need to check if it has all positive principal minors.

Most concretely, we have
$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\cos\alpha & 0 & -(\sin\alpha) e^{i\beta}\\
2\cos\alpha & 2 & (\sin\alpha) e^{i\beta} & 0\\
 0 & (\sin\alpha) e^{-i\beta} & 2 & 2\cos\alpha\\
- (\sin\alpha) e^{-i\beta} & 0 & 2\cos\alpha & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $g_i$ be the $i$th principal minor of $G$, that is, the determinant of the submatrix of $G$ from the first $i$ rows and columns. Then a direct calculation gives
\begin{align*}
g_1 &= 2,\\
g_2 &= 4\sin^2\alpha,\\
g_3 &= 6\sin^2\alpha,\\
g_4 &= 9\sin^4\alpha.
\end{align*}
Therefore the matrix $G$ is positive-definite when $\sin\alpha\neq 0$. That happens when $\eta_2$ is not the north or south pole.

Therefore, the final conclusion is that your $G$ is positive-definite whenever $\eta_1\neq \pm \eta_2$ on $S^2$.

**Added for simplification.** We can actually just let $\beta=0$ in the above calculation. (This corresponds to choosing the coordinate system so that $\eta_1$ is at the north pole, and $\eta_2$ is in the $xz-$plane.) Then $e^{i\beta}=1$, and the matrix $G$ is totally real and symmetric as
$$
G=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
-B & A
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Such a matrix is actually the corresponding real form of the Hermitian matrix
$$
H= A-iB = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha\\
2\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $G$ is positive-definite as a symmetric real matrix iff $H$ is positive-definite as a Hermitian matrix. The reason is that for $$\vec w=(w_1, w_2)^T = (x_1+iy_1, x_2+iy_2)^T,$$
let
$$
\vec v = (x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)^T,
$$
and one can check that
$$ \vec v^T G \vec v = \vec w^T H \vec w.$$
Now the pricipal minors of $H$ are
$$
h_1 = 2,\quad h_2 = 3\sin^2\alpha.
$$
We arrive at the same conclusion as before, although this time the determinant calculation is very easy.